# Can Poetry download dependencies when building a wheel for offline installation?

Tags: dependency-management, python-poetry

I’d like to download all dependencies for a project when running the poetry build command the output wheel (whl) file includes the downloaded dependencies (for offline installation).

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find a built-in feature for this use case. The closest I got is to export the lock file into a requirements file and then, use pip to download all the dependencies:

```
poetry build
poetry export -f requirements.txt --output dist/requirements.txt
poetry run pip download -r dist/requirements.txt -d dist/wheels
```